# Python3 creating JSON from file txt file directory listing

Tags: python, json

Im looking to convert a file directory listing into some structured data.

A typical listing would look like this.

```
test
|_ animals
|___ cats
|______images
|________ cat1.jpg
|________ cat2.jpg
|______textfile.txt
```

```
    C:\test>dir /s | more
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 0036-34A6

 Directory of C:\test

01-Mar-20  04:25 PM    <DIR>          .
01-Mar-20  04:25 PM    <DIR>          ..
01-Mar-20  04:25 PM    <DIR>          animals
               0 File(s)              0 bytes

 Directory of C:\test\animals

01-Mar-20  04:25 PM    <DIR>          .
01-Mar-20  04:25 PM    <DIR>          ..
01-Mar-20  04:26 PM    <DIR>          cats
               0 File(s)              0 bytes

 Directory of C:\test\animals\cats

01-Mar-20  04:26 PM    <DIR>          .
01-Mar-20  04:26 PM    <DIR>          ..
01-Mar-20  04:26 PM    <DIR>          images
01-Mar-20  04:26 PM                 0 textfile.txt
               1 File(s)              0 bytes

 Directory of C:\test\animals\cats\images

01-Mar-20  04:26 PM    <DIR>          .
01-Mar-20  04:26 PM    <DIR>          ..
01-Mar-20  04:26 PM                 0 cat1.jpg
01-Mar-20  04:26 PM                 0 cat2.jpg
               2 File(s)              0 bytes

     Total Files Listed:
               3 File(s)              0 bytes
              11 Dir(s)  94,860,820,480 bytes free
```

Ive built the code to iterate through the lines and save it into csv, but would like to save it into json instead so that I can retain the hierarchy.

at the end i would like the json to look something like,

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "type": "Folder",
      "name": "animals",
      "path": "c:\\test\\animals",
      "children": [
        {
          "type": "folder",
          "name": "cats",
          "path": "c:\\test\\animals\\cats\\",
          "children": [
            {
              "type": "folder",
              "name": "images",
              "path": "c:\\test\\animals\\cats\\images\\",
              "children": [
                {
                  "type": "file",
                  "name": "cat1.jpg",
                  "filetype": "jpg",
                  "size": "0",
                  "path": "c:\\test\\animals\\cats\\images\\cat1.jpg"
                },
                {
                  "type": "file",
                  "name": "cat2.jpg",
                  "size": "0",
                  "filetype": "jpg",
                  "path": "c:\\test\\animals\\cats\\images\\cat2.jpg"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "type": "file",
              "name": "textfile.txt",
              "filetype": "txt",
              "size": "0",
              "path": "c:\\test\\animals\\cats\\textfile.txt"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

Or do I need to build the hierarchy manually by iterating through the lines? 
I would assume there must be some python library that handles this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

**You can use recursion to traverse the given directory recursively. For this you can use the built in module in python `os` which provides various methods for file system information and manipulation. To write the json data to the file you can use the built-in `json` module. 
This can be achieved by the following code:**

```
import os
import json

source = "your_source_dir_path" # --> path to the source dir

def dumptree(source):
    info_list = []
    for filename in os.listdir(source):
        info = dict()

        fullpath = os.path.join(source, filename)
        if os.path.isfile(fullpath):
            info["type"] = "file"
            info["name"] = filename
            info["filetype"] = os.path.splitext(filename)[-1]
            info["size"] = os.path.getsize(fullpath)
            info["path"] = fullpath
        else:
            info["type"] = "folder"
            info["name"] = filename
            info["path"] = fullpath
            info["children"] = dumptree(fullpath)

        info_list.append(info)

    return info_list

data = {}
data["data"] = dumptree(source)
with open("output_filename.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(data, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
```

Comment: This would be great if I was running this on the file system where the files are located. Unfortunately, i only get provided with the directory listings in txt format.